# Syslog messages show up as "Unknown" when I use Python's logging.handlers.SysLogHandler

Tags: python, logging, syslog

When I run this on my mac:

```
import logging.handlers
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

syslog_address = '/var/run/syslog'
logger.addHandler(logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(syslog_address))
logger.error("What the crap?")
```

It shows up like this in the syslog:

```
Oct 18 19:02:06 nick Unknown[4294967295] <Error>: What the crap?
```

Why is it Unknown?  Shouldn't it be smart enough to name itself after the script's **name**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get what you need, you should add a formatter to the handler so you don't have to manually format every message yourself.

```
import logging.handlers
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

syslog_address = '/var/run/syslog'

handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(syslog_address)
# create the formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s: [%(levelname)s] %(message)s')
# plug this formatter into your handler(s)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.error("What the crap?")
```

You should now find that you see entries in syslog as you'd expect:

```
Jul  4 14:34:40 ip-127-0-0-1 script_name.py: [ERROR] What the crap?
```

Comment: It seems that the API for handlers differs between some versions of Python.  I just had to do the following to handle our 2 environments:

    try:
        handler.addFormatter(formatter)
    except AttributeError, e:
        handler.formatter = formatter

Answer (score 15):

I think the APP-NAME (which indicates the source) is an optional component in the syslog header. The latest version of SysLogHandler (for Python 3.3) includes support for an APP-NAME (called `ident` as per the C syslog API), but it's not available in earlier versions. See [this Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue12419).

If you prepend your script name to all messages, you will get the desired effect. For example,

```
logger.error('foo: What\'s up?')
```

will display e.g.

> 19/10/2011 13:51:17 foo[2147483647] What's up?

in the log.

Comment: According to the python issue you can set the property `handler.ident` to a string and it will be automatically prepended to all messages.

Comment: @Hubro true, that's a later addition to the logging code - it was added as a resulted of the linked issue. This solution is for older Python versions.

Comment: Correction after testing, it's not enough to just give `handler.ident` the value `"app_name"`, as it will just prepend it as-is, and you end up with a log line like `"app_nameThis is a test"`. You have to include `": "`  manually.

Answer (score 3):

It can be found all list which word matches what in the list you can find at [this link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes)

If you need more you can have a look further example:

```
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
import logging

def log(self, severity=logging.DEBUG, message=None):
    """
    Log utility for system wide logging needs
    @param severity Log severity
    @param message Log message
    @return
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(severity)
    syslog = SysLogHandler(address="/dev/log")
    syslog.setFormatter(
          logging.Formatter("%(module)s-%(processName)s[%(process)d]: %(name)s: %(message)s")
    )
    logger.addHandler(syslog)
    logger.log(severity, message)
```

It is quite simple and I use this method as a global logging package in my projects.